# What is the name of these SSD M.2 heatsink copper sheets?

Tags: laptop, ssd, cooling, heatsink

Would like to add a 2nd SSD in a Lenovo ThinkBook 16p G2 ACH laptop.

According to the [Hardware Maintenance Manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_thinkbook_16p_gen2_en_hmm.pdf) you have to wrap it in the following:

[image]

(this then gets in contact with a silicon pad which is already in the laptop)

This is what they say about it:

*Go to https://support.lenovo.com/partslookup to look up the Lenovo part numbers of the following
replacement parts:*

*Solid-state drive (SSD) Cu Foil mylar*

However, there are zero results on their site and searching online for these terms is rather inconclusive.

I suppose that people might call these differently than Lenovo does...

**Question:**

What is the name of this foldable copper sheet for SSDs?

Comment: It literally says in the image... SSD Cu (chemical symbol for copper) foil mylar.

Comment: I know... search the web about that, you get some weird AliExpress stuff...

Comment: From that manual, it appears you need a whole kit: "thermalpads", SSD holders, and "SSD Cu foil mylar" are all *not* reusable. Perhaps a Lenovo service place might sell them... or not. Perhaps https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ could help?

Comment: It's Cu (Copper) Foil Mylar Tape (also known as polyester tape).  It's likely overkill.  You could probably just an appropriate thick thermal pad.  I found polyester tape on Amazon.  I would just skip it....

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The second one has never been in used since it's never been in contact with a SSD.

Comment: @Ramhound No it's not, the other side is not conductive.

Comment: @aybe - Yes, it is. Your screenshots literally gave that name of the tape. I found plenty of results which were nonconducting

Comment: Well... I've was searching for `Solid-state drive (SSD) Cu Foil mylar` without success, I simply searched for `(SSD) Cu Foil mylar` and yep, results are good now :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about parts recognition.